# Smalltalk with GUI on Mac OS X Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I need some smalltalk with GUI for my homework, and I'm running Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

I've seen that unix users usually use **GNU Smalltalk** and **GTK+**.

I've tried to install them from different versions of sources and all of them give some errors.

Then I've used MacPorts, but that installation breaks GTK+ bindings for gst.

Finally I've tried to install it using **fing** package manager (because GNU states that I should install everything nice) but there is no smalltalk package for **10.7** OS (though there is for previous ones).

Is there some way to use smalltalk under Mac OS Lion, or should I for example run Ubuntu on virtual machine?

Comment: Squeak or Pharo are both good. Most of these videos (besides how to install) work for either: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6601A198DF14788D&feature=view_all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also try Pharo, which is a fork of Squeak.

http://www.pharo-project.org/home

Comment: this is and interesting option :). Though it's hard to get used to some gui right-click and 'Do It', after some command-lining and emacs coding. I'll look into it, and least the website and screenshots look better then Squeak :)

Comment: Graphical Smalltalks do tend to be more mouse heavy, but for things like 'Do It', there are generally keyboard shortcuts.  For example, in Pharo Ctrl-D/Cmd-D will do that.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's just that I'm used to more command line programing :)

Answer (score 5):

Uko,

Have you looked at Squeak? Its an open source version of Smalltalk which is really fun to use and is supported on most platforms.

See:

http://squeak.org/

You will need a specific SqueakVM for the Mac:

http://www.squeakvm.org/mac/

Let me know if you have any further questions...

Answer (score 4):

Squeak or Pharo are real Smalltalks (unlike GNU). This means they have a Smalltalk specific IDE. IDEs were invented by the creators of Smalltalk, so whatever you think you know about IDEs, you probably don't.

My video series, Squeak from the very start, shows how to download the latest Squeak Smalltalk and get started with it. Pharo isn't any harder to install either.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6601A198DF14788D&feature=view_all

Answer (score 1):

You can also give the Personal Use version of VisualWorks a spin:

http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/developer-community/trying-cincom-smalltalk/try-cincom-smalltalk/

I'm assuming you'll get a 7.8(.1?) version there. The OSX skin is pretty dated. I promise it's getting better. Look for 7.9 soon now.